# IsStreetsideSupported always return false

Tags: uwp, uwp-maps

I use surface pro 4 to develop window 10 uwp app.
the MapControl.IsStreetsideSupported and MapControl.Is3DSupported always return false, i don't konw why.

```
  if (MapControl1.IsStreetsideSupported)
```

Answer (score 0):

Streetside and 3D are only supported in certain markets. What region are you looking for 3D support in?

Comment: I just run MapControl demo from MS, it's always return false. I'm in China, but i want to know how to use this feature in China to look Location in USA

Comment: Unfortunately, China is one of the markets that Streetside and 3D are not supported in. There are specific government requirements that need to be met and 3D and Streetside do not meet those requirements currently. Since the mapping capability is part of the operating system, the functionality is disabled based on the operating system market, not based on where you are looking.

Comment: but how can i test this function in china if i will publish the app to other country?

Comment: There is no way to test this with a Chinese version of the OS. You would need to install a non-China version.